# error with wamp server error #2002 could not open phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, wampserver

i have installed the **wamp server**  and i was work perfectly but now i try to open the **phpMyAdmin**  but the server display this error

**Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**
can anyone help me ????

## mysql.log

```
130816 10:30:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130816 10:30:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130816 10:30:32  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130816 10:30:33 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 6780464
130816 10:30:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130816 10:30:34 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130816 10:30:34 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130816 10:30:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130816 10:30:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130816 10:30:35 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130816 10:31:48 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130816 10:31:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130816 10:31:48  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130816 10:31:50  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 6780474
130816 10:31:50 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130816 10:31:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130816 10:31:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130816 10:31:52  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130816 10:31:53 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 6780474
130816 10:31:53 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130816 10:31:53 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130816 10:31:53 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130816 10:31:53 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130816 10:31:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130816 10:31:53 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: please post the mysql log from c:\wamp\logs

Comment: i edit my question and added  the mysql.log hope that will help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to click on the WAMP server icon in the system tray and go to mySQL and my.ini. Open the file in a text editor like notepad. At the top of the page there should be a line

```
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

change that to

```
socket = c:/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Save the file and try running phpmyAdmin. Restart wamp. It should work perfectly.

If this does not fix the error for you let me know and I will try and help.

Comment: I also have the same problem, i changed socket = /tmp/mysql.sock to socket = c:/tmp/mysql.sock, but again getting same error. any solution?

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is to

- First exit your wampserver
- Then go to "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data"
- Note: don't delete the folders, it is important then after that delete all the files except for the folders
- After that don't close "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data"
- Now open again the wampserver and wait until the wampserver tray turn to green

and that's it!

Comment: it works but cannot open table in database if delete the 3 files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1. How to fix the errors in the 3 files?

Comment: does not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same issue, I searched on google for any better solution but i found nothing helpful. So, what I did, is: Unistall Wamp, delete the wamp folder from C and reinstalled wamp again. I KNOW is not the best solution but it's still the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when `wampmysqld` service was blocked in `stopping` state. If you happen to have the same problem again you can try the following :

1. Shut down wamp server
2. Click Start.
3. In the Start Search box, type `cmd`, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. (Run console as Administrator)
4. Type `Taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq wampmysqld` and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
5. If everything works as expected you will see `SUCCESS: The process with PID XXXX has been terminated.`
6. Restart wamp server, the icon should be green again.

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is remove service from  service section of mysql tab. And install service again. Now all working fine. Your wamp turns into green.

Thanks,
zozothemes

Answer (score 0):

Alright ,I tried few solutions and they didn't work, Then i realized i should restart WAMP server. So i tried to start wamp server's tray and STOPPED ALL  SERVICES AND STARTED ALL THE SERVICES, .... Try that, it worked for me,Have a wonderful day :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the wampmysql service which makes the icon green. If nothing works, must check your services by going to control panel>services and search for this service. Once found, check whether it has been started or disabled. Start it and there you go :)