# WAMP - phpMyAdmin [Error #2002]

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I got this issue unknowingly and its been 3 days for now that this problem isn't resolved.

When I try to access `phpMyAdmin` it throws a MySQL error #2002. I thought it was the hosts file problem, so I've gone into it and uncommented the **"127.0.0.1  localhost"**, this too doesn't work. Seen all the possible solutions over stackoverflow, done all the trial and error methods, gone through videos, no result. Even I re-installed WAMP thrice, at one stage I removed WAMP totally and installed XAMPP, it's the same result.

Checked the MySQL log file, nothing is in there. Checked the php configuration file, it's all perfect, nothing seems to be in trouble, even uninstalled skype and utorrent. Adding the screenshot for reference. Any suggestions before I format my hard drive would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error with wamp server error #2002 could not open phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268378/error-with-wamp-server-error-2002-could-not-open-phpmyadmin)

Comment: Sorry, may be the error number matches, but read the error, it doesn't match, although I have tried that solution too, it doesn't work.

Comment: which windows version?

Comment: @BhanuPrakash  Ah, the server socket error makes me think you are running on an OS that has IPv6 configured.


click wampserver -> Apache -> httpd.conf


Look forthe "Listen" command

Change it from
Listen 80

to

Listen 0.0.0.0:80


This makes apache only listen on the IPV4 network and may solve your problem

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king I opened the file, and it's like this by default

##Listen 12.34.56.78:80Listen 0.0.0.0:80Listen [::0]:80##

Do I need to do anything more than that ?

Comment: @BhanuPrakash Have you changed it as I mentioned?

Comment: There is no change to be done there I think so, as you told its already there, if any changes manually i need to do, tell me, i'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure but try this,

You will find a file named **"my.cnf"** on the same partition you installed **wampserver** mostly for another server you installed before search for it and delete it...

You can also have a look at this. It have mentioned some useful way.
[Access Denied when opening phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702051/access-denied-when-opening-phpmyadmin)

Comment: wampserver is installed in my C drive, and I searched for my.cnf file in the whole C drive. The result is "No items match your search." Any other alternatives please. That link you have provided, I've already checked it and done the trial and error methods, sadly no solution.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash There are many solution mentioned. have you tried it because the one worked for someone case may not word for others.

Comment: Yes, I tried all those, nothing worked for me, looks like formatting HDD would only clear the problem..

Comment: @BhanuPrakash   You can asked moderator for help.

Comment: Can you suggest me those moderators ?

Comment: flag the question is an option, other way may be possible

Comment: Enough of research has been done, no one provided the solution, the only thing I did is formatting HDD and it solved the problem.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash bro u have to have patient, some one will help you for sure.

Comment: Someone may help? I have patience, I gotta submit the project to one of my clients and my time was running out. Anyways bro, thanks a lot for your help in this but atlast problem was solved atleast :) Happy New Year ;)

Comment: Use  
start a bounty. that may help.